# Django REST framework. Сериализация по внешнему ключу

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Мне хотелось бы сериализавать класс `Project`:

```
from django.db import models


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название',
                             max_length=255)
    number = models.CharField('Номер',
                              max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField('Описание')
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey('organization.Employee',
                                        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True,
                                        verbose_name='Ответственный',)
    start_date = models.DateField('Дата начала проекта')
    finish_date = models.DateField('Дата окончания проекта')

    class Meta:
        ordering = [
            'number',
            'project_manager',
        ]
        verbose_name = 'Проект'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Проекты'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.number,
                                self.title)
```

В поле **`project_manager`** мне нужно "не полностью" сериализовать класс **`Employee`**:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя',
                                  max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField('Фамилия',
                                 max_length=45)
    group = models.ForeignKey('organization.Department',
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True)
    position = models.ForeignKey('organization.Position',
                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                 verbose_name='Должность',)
    email = models.EmailField('Email')
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('projects.Project',
                                      verbose_name='Проекты',
                                      null=True,
                                      blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = [
            'group',
            'last_name',
        ]
        verbose_name = 'Сотрудник'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сотрудники'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.last_name,
                              self.first_name)
```

И в поле **`position`** сериализовать название должности (`title`) из класса `Position`

Я бы хотел получить примерно следующее:

```
{
    "count": 42,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "Экспорт друзей VK в Google Contacts",
            "number": "12-94",
            "description": "После покупки андроид-фона, появилась необходимо ...",
            "project_manager": {
                "first_name": "Ирма",
                "last_name": "Капустина",
                "group": 6,
                "position": "Начальник отдела",
                "email": "Hento1942@jourrapide.com"
            },
            "start_date": "2019-06-07",
            "finish_date": "2019-07-26"
        },
        {
             ...
```

Для этого мне пришлось написать отдельный сериализатор, для получения только нужных полей класса **`Employee`** и в нем метод для получения должности:

```
def get_position_title(self, obj):
        return obj.position.title
```

Но мне кажется, то ли я где-то переусложнил, то ли не использовал какие-то возможности REST? Есть ли более понятный и простой способ получить нужный json? И как мой способ "многоуровневой сериализации" будет работать, когда количество данных увеличиться (~10000 записей)?

Comment: Поле `group` в требуемом json конечно же нужно сериализовать аналогично полю `position`.

Comment: Вполне корректный способ. Для большого количества записей одним из минусов будет повтор информации о `project_manager`. Для вашего примера если Ирма Капустина будет менеджером в 5000 из 10000 проектов вы получите 5000 копий одного и того же json. Этого можно избежать при желании.